# Convert Varchar to Date type (not just to run a query, actually changing the column on the table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This was asked several times but I wasn't able to implement any of the answers.

I have a table with a column with Dates that has been created as VARCHAR, I want to convert it to Date(103).

I've seen several responses with the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

This will work nicely to convert the result of a query...but I want to convert the actual column not just when I do a select query.

I probably just don't understand where to put this line of SQL code. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Kudos for wanting to change the column to the proper date type. Be aware that once you do that, display formatting of the date value will be controlled entirely by the application. Also applications that provide the date value should specify a strongly-typed date parameter to avoid ambiguous string parsing by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `DATE(103)`; dates are stored using an *internal* format.  I'll assume that is the format of the *string*.

What to do?  Change the string to something that can be implicitly converted to a date.  Then change the column:

```
update t
    set datecol = convert(date, datecol, 103);

alter t alter datecol date;
```

If this returns an error, you need to figure out where the values don't convert properly.  That would use:

```
select datecol
from t
where try_convert(date, datecol, 103) is null and
      datecol is not null;
```

You'll need to figure out how to fix the broken values.  And in the process learn one important reason not to store date/time values as strings.

Comment: Thank you for the help Gordon,  but after I ran your lines i got this error : Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Could this be because I have nulls on this column?

Comment: @Jbrit2020 . . . No, `NULL`s would not affect that.

Comment: That worked, there was a single row where the date was for some reason not converting. still don't know why. tried to find any special characters or anything but there was nothing out of ordinary...anyway thanks it's now working properly.